# Pyocr doesn't recognize get_available_tools

Tags: python, ocr

I'm using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyocr/0.1.2 for text recognition from images
my script is as follows :

```
from PIL import Image
import sys
import pyocr
import pyocr.builders

tools = pyocr.get_available_tools()
if len(tools) == 0:
    print("No OCR tool found")
    sys.exit(1)
tool = tools[0]
print("Will use tool '%s'" % (tool.get_name()))

langs = tool.get_available_languages()
print("Available languages: %s" % ", ".join(langs))
lang = langs[0]
print("Will use lang '%s'" % (lang))

txt = tool.image_to_string(Image.open('http://www.domain.com/fr/i/3518721/phone'),
                           lang=lang,
                           builder=pyocr.builders.TextBuilder())
word_boxes = tool.image_to_string(Image.open('http://www.domain.com/fr/i/3518721/phone'),
                                  lang=lang,
                                  builder=pyocr.builders.WordBoxBuilder())
line_and_word_boxes = tool.image_to_string(
        Image.open('http://www.domain.com/fr/i/3518721/phone'), lang=lang,
        builder=pyocr.builders.LineBoxBuilder())
```

when I run the script i have this error message :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "./test.py", line 6, in 
>       tools = pyocr.get_available_tools()
>   AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_available_tools'

What seems to be the problem officers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your imports to look like this:

```
from PIL import Image
import sys
from pyocr import pyocr
from pyocr import builders
```

Now `pyocr.get_available_tools()` will work because you have imported the module. But `pyocr.builders.WordBoxBuilder()` wont work because builders is imported on its own namespace. You'd need to change them to `builders.WordBoxBuilder()` ditto for TextBuilder and LineBoxBuilder.

Comment: OK I'm thinking `import pyocr` on the next lines shadowed my answer. I'm adding the whole import lines.

Comment: Your answer seems to be the best practice, but my problem was solved by reinstalling it as I was running an obsolete version.